# Fail to verify RSA signature on server side that was created using Javascript on client side

Tags: javascript, django, cryptography, rsa, digital-signature

I'm using [forge](https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#rsa) on the client where I create the signature as follows.

```
//Client Side
var md = forge.md.sha256.create();
            md.update(encryptedVote, 'utf8');
            var pss = forge.pss.create({
            md: forge.md.sha256.create(),
            mgf: forge.mgf.mgf1.create(forge.md.sha256.create()),
            saltLength: 20
            });
            var signature = privateKey.sign(md, pss);
```

Then later on the server I try to verify the signature using the [cryptography library](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/hazmat/primitives/asymmetric/rsa/#verification) as follows.

```
#server side
user_public_key_loaded.verify(
            signature,
            enc_encrypted_vote,
            padding.PSS(
                mgf=padding.MGF1(hashes.SHA256()),
                salt_length=20
            ),
            hashes.SHA256()
        )
```

I get consistently an Invalid signature error. I tried changing the encoding on the client to `md.update(encryptedVote, 'latin1');` and now sometimes works some others it doesn't.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you perform `enc_encrypted_vote.encode('utf-8')` in the server/Hazmat part (of course using `md.update(encryptedVote, 'utf8')` on the client side)?

Comment: I found hy sometimes it worked an sometimes it didn't. before verifying I was putting the JSON data into a list by doing `my_list = list(my_dict.values())`. And accessing the signature and vote by doing `my_list[0]` and `my_list[1]`. Apparently the order of the data in the list is random and changes from time to time. Thus the signature and vote were switching place in my function and sometimes it worked some others it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I found hy sometimes it worked an sometimes it didn't. before verifying I was putting the JSON data into a list by doing `my_list = list(my_dict.values())`. And accessing the signature and vote by doing `my_list[0]` and `my_list[1]`. Apparently the order of the data in the list is random and changes from time to time. Thus the signature and vote were switching place in my function and sometimes it worked some others it didn't.